# LINQ for diffing sets

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following arrays:

```
var original= new int[] { 2, 1, 3 };
var target = new int[] { 1, 3, 4 };
enum Operation {Added,Removed}
```

I would like to execute a LINQ query that would return the following:

```
{{2,Removed},{4,Added}}
```

Limitation: I would like LINQ to perform this very efficiently and avoid and O(n^2) style algorithms.

Comment: Can you explain the reasons for your requirements in case there is a better solution than using LINQ?

Comment: Sure, I am comparing two long lists of items quite frequently to look for updates, so I need to scale here.

Comment: Also, SymmetricExceptWith does not really cut it ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps a LINQ solution is not the best option in this case.

This will produce a dictionary with the result that you want.

```
Dictionary<int, Operation> difference = new Dictionary<int,Operation>();
foreach (int value in original) {
    difference.Add(value, Operation.Removed);
}
foreach (int value in target) {
    if (difference.ContainsKey(value)) {
        difference.Remove(value);
    } else {
        difference.Add(value, Operation.Added);
    }
}
```

To keep the size of the dictionary down, perhaps it's possible to loop the enumerations in parallell. I'll have a look at that...

Edit:
Here it is:

```
Dictionary<int, Operation> difference = new Dictionary<int,Operation>();
IEnumerator<int> o = ((IEnumerable<int>)original).GetEnumerator();
IEnumerator<int> t = ((IEnumerable<int>)target).GetEnumerator();
bool oActive=true, tActive=true;
while (oActive || tActive) {
    if (oActive && (oActive = o.MoveNext())) {
        if (difference.ContainsKey(o.Current)) {
            difference.Remove(o.Current);
        } else {
            difference.Add(o.Current, Operation.Removed);
        }
    }
    if (tActive && (tActive = t.MoveNext())) {
        if (difference.ContainsKey(t.Current)) {
            difference.Remove(t.Current);
        } else {
            difference.Add(t.Current, Operation.Added);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit2:
I did some performance testing. The first version runs 10%-20% faster, both with sorted lists and randomly ordered lists.

I made lists with numbers from 1 to 100000, randomly skipping 10% of the numbers. On my machine the first version of the code matches the lists in about 16 ms.

Comment: yerp, its pretty much the solution im going for, but I am going to try and encapsulate it nicely in an extension method

Comment: Right... To make it look like it's LINQ... ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
enum Operation { Added, Removed, }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var original = new int[] { 2, 1, 3 };
    var target = new int[] { 1, 3, 4 };

    var result = original.Except(target)
        .Select(i => new { Value = i, Operation = Operation.Removed, })
        .Concat(
            target.Except(original)
            .Select(i => new { Value = i, Operation = Operation.Added, })
            );

    foreach (var item in result)
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", item.Value, item.Operation);
}
```

I don't think you can do this with LINQ using only a single pass given the stock LINQ extension methods but but might be able to code a custom extension method that will. Your trade off will likely be the loss of deferred execution. It would be interesting to compare the relative performance of both.

Comment: This is about 30% slower than the dictionary in my benchmark, but it is much more concise

Answer (score 0):

You are out of luck.  If, as you stated in the comments, the lists are not sorted you can't compute the difference you seek in a single forward pass.  Consider:

```
{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ...
{ 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, ...
```

At the point where the first difference in encountered (4 vs. 6) it's impossible for you to determine if you are looking at the *removal* of 4 & 5 (as would be the case if both lists were monotonically increasing, or the *insertion* of 6, 7, 8, & 9 as would be the case if the lists continued like so:

```
{ 1, 2, 3,             4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,...
{ 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,...
```

Answer (score 0):

This will achieve the result in a single pass, however I'm not sure of the complexity of the GroupBy operation.

```
var original= new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var target = new int[] { 1, 3, 4 };

var output = original.Select( i => new { I = i, L = "o" } )
    .Concat( target.Select( i => new { I = i, L = "t" } ) )
    .GroupBy( i => i.I ).Where( i => i.Count() == 1 )
.Select( i => new { I = i.Key, S = (i.ElementAt( 0 ).L == "o" ? Operation.Removed : Operation.Added) } );
```

Comment: Seems like the group by stuff does not scale that well. This is about 8x slower than the dictionary solution.

Comment: I was worried that might be the case.

Comment: Enumerable.Range(5, 10000); vs Enumerable.Range(0, 10000);